# How can line breaks be suppressed in Questions using Exercise?

Tags: exercises, answers

I'm trying to display the answers to the different Questions in an Exercise in a single line, since answers to questions are often short. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366436/how-can-line-breaks-be-suppressed-in-subquestions-using-exercise) a workaround was provided but for subQuestions, not Questions. I've naively tried to replace every 'subQuestion' with 'Question' but (not surprisingly) it didn´t work. But in addition, I'd also like to have all the answers in the same line as the number of the exercise: my desired output would be:

**1.1** **(a)** 1st ans. **(b)** 2nd ans.  **(c)** 3rd ans.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[lastexercise, answerdelayed]{exercise}

\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\vspace{-0.3cm} \hrule \vspace{0.2cm} \noindent \bfseries \thesection.\arabic{Exercise} }

\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\vspace{-0.4cm} \hrule \vspace{0.1cm} \noindent \bfseries \thesection.\arabic{Exercise} \ }

\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{(\bfseries \alph{Question})}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{Exercise}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{Exercise}
Guideline
\Question First question blabla
\Question Second question blabla
\Question Third question blabla 
\end{Exercise}

\vspace{3pt} $\vdots$ \vspace{10pt}

\begin{Answer}
\Question 1st ans.
\Question 2nd ans.
\Question 3rd ans.
\end{Answer}

\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

---

The output for that is four lines: one for **1.1**, another for **(a)**, **(b)**, and **(c)**.

---

Here is my failed attempt at doing it myself:

```
\makeatletter
\let \@QuestionHeader@original=\@QuestionHeader
\newcommand{\@QuestionHeader@noItem}{%
    \hspace{1cm}%
    \begingroup
        \@getQuestionInfo
        \QuestionHeaderDifficulty
        \QuestionNB
    \endgroup
    \begingroup
        \@getQuestionInfo
        \QuestionHeaderTitle
    \endgroup%
    \ignorespaces
}%

\newcommand{\QuestionOnSameLine}{%
    \let \@QuestionHeader=\@QuestionHeader@noItem
    \subQuestion
}
\newcommand{\QuestionOnNewLine}{%
    \let \@QuestionHeader=\@QuestionHeader@original
    \Question
}
\makeatother
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the best solution is the simplest. The `exercise` package does some fancy footwork behind the scenes to make the `\Question` commands begin (and later end) implicit list environments (and likewise for `\subQuestion` and `\subsubsQuestion`. But since we just want to compile the answer items on a single line, we can define `\MyQuestion` as:

```
\newcommand{\MyQuestion}{\refstepcounter{Question}%
   \ifnum\value{Question}=1\else
     \quad\fi{\QuestionNB\unskip}~%
   }
```

This uses the `Question` counter defined by `exercise` package to number our answers as before, and inserts a quad space before the question number on all questions after the first and a non-breakable space after the number. I've also enclosed the question number in a group since the existing `\Question` command does the same and your definition of `\QuestionNB` assumes this group (although you might not have realized it. Finally, there's an `\unskip` after `\QuestionNB` since the default definition of `\QuestionNB` has a space there, but since it's a breakable space, we want to get rid of it.

Now if all your answers are going to be in this single-line format, and you don't want to edit your document to change the `\Question` commands to `\MyQuestion`, you can add to the document preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\AtBeginAnswer}{\let\Question\MyQuestion}
```

which will redefine `\Question` to use `\MyQuestion` in the `Answer` environment.

I did not add support for the optional argument to `\Question` to my solution, nor did I deal with `\subQuestion` or `\subsubQuestion`. Those are left as an exercise for the reader.